# In ruby, is there a way to know in the console what a method does?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, console

In Ruby, if i am looking for the methods of a class.
ie:`String.methods.sort`
and i have the following:

```
[:!, :!=, :!~, :<, :<=, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :>, :>=, :__id__,
:__send__, :allocate, :ancestors, :autoload, :autoload?, :class,
:class_eval, :class_exec, :class_variable_defined?,
:class_variable_get, :class_variable_set, :class_variables, :clone,
:const_defined?, :const_get, :const_missing, :const_set, :constants,
:define_singleton_method, :deprecate_constant, :display, :dup,
:enum_for, :eql?, :equal?, :extend, :freeze, :frozen?, :hash, 
:include, :include?, :included_modules, :inspect, :instance_eval,...]
```

Is there a way for me to type a command in the console to explore a method? If i am unfamiliar with `:display` and i want to know what it does, what it returns, is it possible?

If yes, does PHP and javascript have something similar to see method definition in console? It does not look like I have encountered it.

Comment: See [this](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_ri_tool.html) discussion of the stand-alone programs `ri` and `rdoc`.

Comment: Great Thanks.. @CarySwoveland.. Would you know if php and Javascript have similar commands? This is really handy instead of always looking for the documentation online.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not familiar with either of those languages. Perhaps someone else could answer.

Comment: @Krishna JS does not have this built-in. You have to refer the docs. Not sure about PHP.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
help 'String#display'
```

and it'll show the rdoc for the method (the same output that would show from running `ri 'String#display'` outside of irb. You can also just type `help` into irb and it'll go into a mode where you can just keep typing method names and it'll show the rdoc (enter a blank line to exit).

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Simple ... any chance you would know if php and javascript have similar commands?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Pry`, it has a handy shortcut, `show-source`:

```
[1] pry(main)> show-source String.display

From: io.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 15

static VALUE
rb_obj_display(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
{
    VALUE out;

    if (argc == 0) {
        out = rb_stdout;
    }
    else {
        rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &out);
    }
    rb_io_write(out, self);

    return Qnil;
}
```

Comment: How is a beginner expected to understand some source code for a Ruby method?

Comment: @arjun: that's what he asked. This is the ultimate source of truth about "what a method does". More "beginner-friendy" explanation/documentation was already available just one google search away.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev .. i did not know about Pry. thank you very much for mentioning it. I have just started with Ruby and really liking it. One of the other questions i had was if you knew if php and javascript had similar commands. Please let me know if it would be best to start a new thread.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hey if people started reading documentation, StackOverflow would be empty. The OP is a beginner. What you answered could have been additional knowledge for him. It could have been as a passing mention. What SimpleLine wrote above is the answer which OP was looking for.

Comment: @arjun: how do you know what he was looking for?

Comment: @arjun: anyhow, the OP is but one of the readers. Even if he can't fully benefit from this, others might.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not in a school debate. Please read his question and all comments.

Comment: @arjun: the question explicitly asks for ways to see method definition in console. You need to learn to make less assumptions.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Even you answer is bad. One would have to search further what `Qnil` is. Anyone reading would be left further spending time getting definitions of those variable. If you knew so much and cared about other readers, you could have added comments in that code. Your answers and comments goes against [Ruby Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Philosophy)